# Make foam rubber case

Tags: foam, rubber

I am interested in how I might go about making a neoprene (closed cell) foam rubber case for a clock. The clock looks like this:

[image: clock]

The clock is about 10 inches wide at the longest dimension.

I know how to get foam rubber. The problem is how to turn it into a case that opens and closes.

Comment: This isn't quite enough detail. Are you wanting the case to be an exact fit, so it perfectly hugs the clock, or are you just asking about how to make a case in that general shape? Is this something meant for complete enclosure, or a case more like a phone case where the screens/controls would still be exposed?

Comment: If you're using closed cell neoprene, are you hoping that it will be waterproof? Or at least water resistant? If so, consider checking out [this related question](http://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/1819/will-sewing-onto-neoprene-compromise-its-water-resistance).

Answer (score 2):

When you suggest that you are using foam rubber, the term invokes many different types of materials with the same name. The density and stiffness of the various choices provide some challenge to a good design.

The better options include neoprene and also EVA foam. The latter is relatively inexpensive and can be found in the form of floor cushion squares with puzzle cut edges. It is rigid enough from which you can build a box, yet protective enough for your clock.

Additionally, one can find it in various colors, although grey is most common and probably the least expensive.

The foam will melt if you use hot glue to assemble the box. A better choice is a contact cement, specifically a water based product to prevent the foam from dissolving from the cement. Epoxy will also work well, but takes longer to cure.

For a lid to open and close, you can secure a piece of thin leather (long lasting, durable, flexible to one edge and the top or front. Embed magnets in the foam edge to match and you'll have a secure closing system as well.

EDIT: with the additional awareness that the foam is neoprene, I've found there is a solvent based contact adhesive specifically for neoprene. Search for "contact adhesive for neoprene rubber" and you'll have plenty of returns. Amazon lists many and I'm sure there are other sources.

You don't have to have thick rubber to make the magnet idea work either. You can bond a magnet inside a flap of rubber in the box and another flap of rubber in the lid. Use as many as needed to ensure a solid closure.

One might suggest velcro, aka hook-and-loop, but my experience with that material is that it eventually loses grip, as the loops will pull open over time.

Mechanical clasps can be mounted to thin panels of wood which would be bonded using the aforementioned contact cement, but the flexibility of the enclosure may make that too much of a challenge.

Comment: Material is closed-cell neoprene foam rubber.

Comment: updated answer to reflect additional information

Comment: You can also use a small suitcase from a thrift store as the case. I used a $10 suitcase and a mattress pad to make a case for a 16-track mixer. Although I suspect I should upgrade that case with better foam.